# pass a list to view to bind an autocomplete search box

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

The problem is, when the page loads I want the auto search to be bound, in order to do so, I have no idea I should use jsonresult or only action result does that?to point out the problem here is what I have done in my controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult IndexSearch () {
    //List of cars            
    var CarList = (from d in DB.AccessinfoCars select new {

        Town = d.City_name,
            CarName = d.Car_name
    }).ToList ();

    return Json (CarList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the above code, I don't know if should use `actionResult` or `jsonResult` to achieve what I want, and I should pass with viewBag or Ajax call?

In my View, I simply want to bind the following Autocomplete:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                              .Name("CarName") //The name of the AutoComplete is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
                              .DataTextField("input") //Specify which property of the Product to be used by the AutoComplete.
                              .DataSource(source =>
                               {
                                  source.Read(read =>
                                  {
                                      read.Action("IndexSearch", "Overview"); //Set the Action and Controller names.
                                  })
                                  .ServerFiltering(true); //If true, the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
                               })
                            )
```

but to bind that how should I get the data?

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/configuration/datasource

Comment: if you want an autocomplete it would need to be called via AJAX from the browser, otherwise you won't get real-time results. I don't know the kendoAutocomplete but I guess it will generate one automatically, if you tell it the URL to visit, and the name of the parameter to pass. And yes returning JSON would likely make sense. Check the docs of the kendo control to see how to configure it, and what data format it expects to be returned from the server.

Comment: @ADyson but generally if i want to call a controll before page load via Ajax,i need to send a parameter right?if there is no parameter to send whats should i do?for example i want to search some one the parameter should be a name or something,if i need a list without parameter what should i do?to use ajax as far as i know i need a parameter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. AJAX calls run _after_ the page / view loads. They are separate HTTP requests. There is one request to your controller which loads the view. Then when the user types into the autocomplete, it will generate a second (AJAX) request to the server, and pass the value which the user just typed. This second request should go to a different action method than the one which loaded the view. This separate action method should be the one which accepts the parameter, and returns JSON. If the user types more, it generates another AJAX request, and so on...

Comment: P.S. If you want your action method to return all the values whenever no parameter is sent, then you can just make the parameter optional.

Comment: @ADyson i would appreacite if you write an example

Comment: That link given by ocanal in the first comment (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/configuration/datasource) already contains an example. See the 3rd code snippet in that page. Of course in that example you are not actually creating the AJAX code yourself, you are simply telling the Kendo control which URL to send the ajax request to, and letting it do the rest. In your version you probably want to change `dataType: "jsonp"` to `dataType: "json"` but apart from that it ought to be similar. You can check the docs to see what other options are available.

Answer (score 1):

> Ajax

[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetAutocomplete(string prefix)
    {
        var CarList=(from d in DB.AccessinfoCars
                     select new  {
                         Town=d.City_name,
                         CarName=d.Car_name
                     }).ToList();

```
    return Json(CarList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

razor

```
 @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
      .Name("productAutoComplete") //The name of the AutoComplete is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
      .DataTextField("input") //Specify which property of the Product to be used by the AutoComplete.
      .DataSource(source =>
       {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
               read.Action("GetAutocomplete", "yourControler"); //Set the Action and Controller names.
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true); //If true, the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
       })
    )
```

> Model

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    YourModel model = new YourModel();

    return View(model );
}

@model your modal

 @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
        .Name("yourName") //The name of the AutoComplete is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
        .DataTextField("nameYourControl") //Specify which property of the Product to be used by the AutoComplete.
        .BindTo(Model) //Pass the list of Products to the AutoComplete.
        .Filter("contains") //Define the type of the filter, which AutoComplete will use.
    )
```

Comment: can you write in HTML also?because i get error like this Error 29 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: i did what you suggested,when i click on the link which directs me to my view i get "The resource cannot be found"

Comment: Can you use model instead ajax call?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: exist second way use it. i added this way in my answer

Comment: And also try change [HttpPost] to [HttpGet] if you need using specifically AJAX(maybe Kendo make get request)